# Can an individual applicant assert micro entity status for their 6th patent if they asserted small entity status on their 4th application?

Tags: filing, utility-patent, micro-entity, small-entity

Assume Bob files 3 apps as a micro entity, and rightfully so.

Bot misunderstand the rules, and thinks only 4 apps can be claimed as a micro entity.

To twist it further, he decides that patent 5 is more important than 4 so he asserts claims micro entity status on the patent 5, and pays for as a small entity.

Bob subsequently realized that he could have filed both patent 4 and 5 as a micro entity, and now has a 6th patent application.

Can he claim micro entity status thereon since he never used the relief therein for a total of 5 apps or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**  - one is not entitled to a certain number of micro-entity filings.

The section of the [form](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/forms/sb0015a.pdf) one must sign -

> 1.27. (2) APPLICATION FILING LIMIT – Neither the applicant nor the inventor nor a joint inventor has been named as the inventor or a
> joint inventor on *more than four previously filed U.S. patent
> applications*, excluding provisional applications and international
> applications under the Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT) for which the
> basic national fee under 37 CFR 1.492(a) was not paid, and also
> excluding patent applications for which the applicant has assigned all
> ownership rights, or is obligated to assign all ownership rights, as a
> result of the applicant’s previous employment.

You will see that you would be asserting that you have *not previously filed more than four previous applications*. It does not say more than four micro-entity filings.  When it first went into effect anyone who had already filed five applications could not sign this and would never get even one micro-entity filing.

A warning - You might see that this is a simple black and white reading of the words on the form. The things you will deal with in being a pro se applicant will often be much, much, more complicated and subtle.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going right ahead and submit a new question based on this new information!